# show linux disk space use by directory

Tags: linux

There are times I'm over or near my quota on my shared hosting service.
It can often be a chore to track down where large files are. I once found a 500mb zip file in a deeply nested directory.

I'm looking for a Linux command, where I can see how much space each directory and nested subdirectories (in the directory tree) are
 using, sorted in order of disc space use.

I'm unable to get the results I need with variants of the df and du commands.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
du -s * | sort -n
```

Comment: worked! found a giant log.txt file. Baffled where this came from

Answer (score 3):

Check out ncdu. Interactive disk space viewer.